# How to match output form MD5 hash string in C# and in Ruby?

Tags: c#, ruby

Here is code of C#

```
public static string GetMD5Hash(string input)
    {
        System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider x = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] bs = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
        bs = x.ComputeHash(bs);
        System.Text.StringBuilder s = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        foreach (byte b in bs)
        {
            s.Append(b.ToString("x2").ToLower());
        }
        return s.ToString();

    }
```

Here is code of Ruby

```
def getMD5Hash(str）
        bs = Digest::MD5.digest( str.encode( 'UTF-8' ) ).bytes.to_a
        bs = bs.map { |b| b.to_s(16).downcase }
        str_bs = bs.join
        return str_bs
end
```

When I am running ruby code and C# code to encrypt the same string, the result from Ruby is not the same result as C# provided. 
How to modify Ruby code? Thanks a lot

Comment: The C# example use UTF8 yet the Ruby example use UTF16. Why would you expect them to be the same?

Comment: I modified the encoding to UTF8, but it is not the same. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a ruby programmer, but there is something wrong with how you are converting to hex. It looks like values such as '0a' are rendering as 'a' making the output incorrect. Ruby already has a method for this though, `Digest::MD5.hexdigest`, so I'm not sure why anyone would roll their own.

I would write the ruby function:

```
def getMD5Hash(str)
    return Digest::MD5.hexdigest(str.encode( 'UTF-8' ))
end
```

Comment: I try to change the utf-8 in ruby, but the result is not the same. And I need to how to modify ruby code? Thanks a lot

Comment: @JiameiWan See my update. The ruby code has a bug in it but I don't know enough ruby to point at the exact error. Use `Digest::MD5.hexdigest` instead.

Comment: You mean: Digest::MD5.hexdigest(str)?

Comment: the result from your code is the same as mine, it is not the same as the ruby. And your point that values such as '0a' are rendering as 'a' making the output incorrect, i think so, but I don't know how to resolve it. Thanks for your helping

Comment: @JiameiWan I have no idea what you mean then, because I did not get the same result from your code and mine in ruby. I did get the same result for my code in C# and Ruby. Edit the question with the input and output you are using in both C# and Ruby.

Comment: Yes, Ruby code is right. And Sorry, I've made a mistake. Thanks for your great helping.